# Sharepoint calculated field rendering

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, list-form, client-side-rendering

Currently in my SharePoint list, the fields are displayed in Tabs format
But When I am adding the calculated column, it is not getting displayed on New/Edit forms. but it is visible on the display form.

CSR field rendering has been used. Please suggest if am missing something to add/update for he calculated column.

Comment: Calculated columns won't be added/visible in new/edit forms, this is by design.

Comment: Have you used any code to show these calculated fields on new/edit forms? If yes, please add code to your question.

Answer (score 3):

**This is by design**.

The calculated fields will not be shown on New/Edit form of SharePoint list. It will visible on the display form of list or in list views only.

Comment: Hi, does this answers your question? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will help others with same question to find the correct answer easily. It also removes the question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

The calculated field is calculated after the item added or updated.

We cannot add or edit value for the calculated column, so it is not displayed on the New/Edit forms, they are displayed on the display form only or in views.